# Installing Ruby On Rails - Issues with gem (and no RVM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm having this issue whenever i run "gem install rails":

```
usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

Ruby and Rubygems were both installed from source. I've installed libyaml from source and from apt-get. I'm running ubuntu 12.04. I am **NOT** running RVM as far as I know (trying "rvm" returns "bla bla bla not installed apt-get". I'm pretty sure this speaks of 2 separate issues but I need solutions to both. Thanks.

Comment: @AntarrByrd I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I would suggest you use RVM it makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

RVM is best tool for easily install, manage, and work with multiple ruby environments.
https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ follow the instructions in this link to get RVM working.
Then you should install 'libtool' before you install 'libyaml'.

```
 sudo apt-get install libtool
 rvm pkg install libyaml
 rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

these commands are using for installing libyaml.
After installing this you can install rails using

```
 gem install rails
```